# Laravel validation errors are appearing randomly in my view

Tags: validation, laravel, view, controller

When I submit my form the validation works randomly, I mean that it sometimes appears and sometimes not, I found out that the validation object is returned by controller but it is not looped in my view always.
here is my code in view:

```
  @if ($errors->any())
        <ul class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
          @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
          @endforeach
          </ul>
        </ul>
    @endif
```

it randomly shows this:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#651 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(1) { ["default"]=> object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)#643 (2) { ["messages":protected]=> array(12) { ["province_code"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "The province code field is required." } ["district_code"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "The district code field is required." } ["training_provider"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(40) "The training provider field is required." } ["training_center"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(38) "The training center field is required." } ["classroom"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(32) "The classroom field is required." } ["course_leader"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(36) "The course leader field is required." } ["shift"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(28) "The shift field is required." } ["start_date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(33) "The start date field is required." } ["end_date"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "The end date field is required." } ["start_time"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(33) "The start time field is required." } ["end_time"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(31) "The end time field is required." } ["course_conduct_days"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(42) "The course conduct days field is required." } } ["format":protected]=> string(8) ":message" } } }<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and then it comes up with empty array!

```
object(Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag)#652 (1) { ["bags":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

Comment: show your controller

Comment: @M0rtiis this is where I check for validation  if($validator->fails()){
    
             return redirect()->back()
             ->withInput(Input::all())->withErrors($validator)->with('districts', $districts)
             ->with('centers', $centers)->with('classrooms', $classrooms);
            }

Comment: so it means that you really have no errors. mb mistakes in rules?

Comment: can you show your full controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I solved this problem, it was a conflict with ajax

Answer (score 0):

Do this if the message bag has errors then only they would be printed

```
@if($errors->has())
<div class="alert alert-danger">
   <ul>
        @foreach($errors->getMessages() as $messages)
            @foreach($messages as $message)
                <li>{{$message}}</li>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Thanks :)